# Reverse SSH tunnel - Fails on Certain Ports

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I'm trying to forward very specific ports using a reverse SSH tunnel. MachineA is the target machine (the one the command is being run from) and MachineB is the tunnel (the one SSH is connecting to and the one public connections will see).

(Port 123 is used as a placeholder for some other port that works).

The command used for the tunnel is:

```
[user@MachineA ~]$ ssh -gnN -R *:500:localhost:500 -R *:311:localhost:311 -R *:123:localhost:123 user@MachineB
```

It shows the following output, indicating certain ports can't be forwarded:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 500
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 311
```

If I go to MachineB I see this before the tunnel starts:

```
[user@MachineB ~]$ netstat -na | grep 500
[user@MachineB ~]$ netstat -na | grep 311
[user@MachineB ~]$ netstat -na | grep 123
[user@MachineB ~]$
```

and this after (where port 123 is a port that I'm successfully tunneling:

```
[user@MachineB ~]$ netstat -na | grep 500
[user@MachineB ~]$ netstat -na | grep 311
[user@MachineB ~]$ netstat -na | grep 123
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
[user@MachineB ~]$
```

It doesn't appear to be a problem with in-use ports. Other ports (like the placeholder 123) forward fine. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

How many of the ports are below 1024?

If you only have problems with low numbered ports, the user on the target machine does not have permission to open 'secure' ports.

If this is the case, login as root on the target machine.